# Does Groovy "as" operator create a subclass at run time for User defined classes?

Tags: groovy, coercion

In Groovy When I write the below code in a groovy script.

```
class Emp {
    public String getId() {
         return "12345";
    }
}

def coercedInstance = [ 
   getId: {
     "99999"
    }
] as Emp

println new Emp().getId()
println coercedInstance .getId()
```

Using the **as** Operator here, am I creating a sub class of the actual Emp class at runtime and providing the method body at run time?

I have seen other stack overflow articles and i have learnt that Groovy uses DefaultGroovyMethods.java & DefaultTypeTransformation.java to do the coercion. But could not figure out if it was subclassing or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, an `as` operator creates an object which type is a subclass of the target class. Using [`DefaultGroovyMethods.asType(Map map, Class clazz)`](https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/GROOVY_2_5_8/src/main/java/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.java#L11805) generates (in a memory) a proxy class that extends given base class.

```groovy
class Emp {

    public String getId() {
        return "12345";
    }
}

def coercedInstance = [
    getId: {
        "99999"
    }
] as Emp

assert (coercedInstance instanceof Emp)
assert (coercedInstance.class != Emp)
assert (Emp.isAssignableFrom(coercedInstance.class))

println coercedInstance.dump() // <Emp1_groovyProxy@229c6181 $closures$delegate$map=[getId:coercion$_run_closure1@7bd4937b]>
```

What happens in your case specifically is the following:

- The `asType` method goes to [line 11816](https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/GROOVY_2_5_8/src/main/java/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.java#L11816) to execute `ProxyGenerator.INSTANCE.instantiateAggregateFromBaseClass(map, clazz);`
- In the next step, [`ProxyGeneratorAdapter`](https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/GROOVY_2_5_8/src/main/groovy/groovy/util/ProxyGenerator.java#L167) object gets created.
- In the last step, [`adapter.proxy(map,constructorArgs)`](https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/GROOVY_2_5_8/src/main/groovy/groovy/util/ProxyGenerator.java#L169) gets called to return a newly generated class that is a proxy of the base class.